# .NET Core runtime forward compatibility

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Our continuous integration is a standard setup in which we have a build server which produces a build and then deploys that build to the application servers. Inevitably, we upgrade the .NET Core SDK's on the build servers before we upgrade the .NET Core runtimes on our application servers.

Are versions of the .NET Core runtime forward compatible such that I can always run builds from the latest SDKs on older runtimes? For example, what happens I build with SDK 2.1.500 and run it on Runtime 2.1.3? This is what we're doing in production and nothing seems to have blown up yet but I'm wondering if this is something we should avoid.

Comment: I believe your instinct is correct and you should avoid it. While the specific situation called out, building on 2.1.500 and running on 2.1.3 is low risk, the larger the gap, the greater the risk.